# python function to compare urls

Tags: python

Hi everyone I'm creating a function to compare urls

I have 4 types of urls:

```
home = 'https://forum.example.fr/'

questions_list = 'https://forum.example.fr/categories'

question = 'https://forum.example.fr/questions'
```

and unknown = anything but those 3

Here is my the code:

```
def bbox_page_type(url):
    home = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/'
    questions_list = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/categories'
    question = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions'
    if url == home:
       print("home.")
    if url == questions_list:
       print("question list.")
    if url == question:
        print("question.")
    if url != home and url != questions_list and url != question:
        print("UNKNOWN.")
url = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/categories'
bbox_page_type(url)
```

the home url is alright , but questions_list and question can be

> [https://forum.example.fr/categories/{categorie_name}'](https://forum.example.fr/categories/%7Bcategorie_name%7D%27)

i want a condition to ignore what comes after the '/'

something like

```
if url == home+/+anything comes after it
```

Comment: Why don't you try using .replace() to replace the home link with an empty string (i.e. nothing)

Comment: There is `if/elif/else`

Comment: You can split the url by '/'. If the url does not have anything after the last '/' it will be an empty string. So something like this `if home.split('/')[3] != '': `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can try:

```
def bbox_page_type(url):
    home = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/'
    questions_list = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/categories'
    question = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions'
    if url == home:
       print("home.")
    elif questions_list in url:
       print("question list.")
    elif question in url:
        print("question.")
    else:
        print("UNKNOWN.")
```

Comment: Can you select your preferred answer, to avoid people thinking it's an open topic?

Comment: yes i was just waiting for the question to pass 5 min so i can accept your questino , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `==` operator, use the `in` operator. The `in` operator also works if the values that are being compared are the same.

So the code would be:

```
def bbox_page_type(url):
    home = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/'
    questions_list = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/categories'
    question = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions'
    if url in home:
       print("home.")
    elif url in questions_list:
       print("question list.")
    elif url in question:
        print("question.")
    else:
        print("UNKNOWN.")

url = 'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/categories'
bbox_page_type(url)


--> question list.
```